# onClick is not working in cardView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I am developing an app in which i am using recyclerView and cardView.I am retrieving data from server and displaying it.When i am trying to implement onclick method on this,it is not working.:

Here is my code for main activity:

```
public class Tab_1_Activity extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
private Config config;
private List<ListItem> upcomingJobs = new ArrayList<>();
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab_1, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.swifeRefresh);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            getData();

            upcomingJobs.clear();
            upcomingJobs.addAll(upcomingJobs);
            // fire the event
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            // uAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    //Make call to AsyncTask
    getData();
    return v;
}
```

For Adapter Class:

```
    public class CardAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {

List<ListItem> items;


public CardAdapter(String[] offer, String[] offerprice, Bitmap[] image, String[] price, String[] url) {
    super();
    items = new ArrayList<ListItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < offer.length; i++) {
        ListItem item = new ListItem();
        item.setoffer(offer[i]);
        item.seturl(url[i]);
        item.setofferprice(offerprice[i]);
        item.setprice(price[i]);
        item.setimage(image[i]);

        items.add(item);
    }
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.card_view_list, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ListItem list = items.get(position);
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(list.getimage());
    holder.offer.setText(list.getoffer());
    holder.url.setText(list.geturl());

    holder.offerprice.setText(list.getofferprice());
    holder.price.setText(list.getprice());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(this) ;


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i=new Intent(v.getContext(),Settings.class);
    v.getContext().startActivity(i);
}


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;
    public View view;

    public TextView offer, offerprice, price, url;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        offer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.offer);
        offerprice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.offerprice);
        price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.offerprice);
        url = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.url);


    }




    }
}
```

card_view_list.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
android:paddingLeft="2dp"
android:paddingRight="2dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/url"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/price"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"
            android:layout_below="@id/url"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/offer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

            android:textColor="@color/textSecondary"
            android:textSize="16sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/offerprice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: You are simply implementing `onClickListener`, you have to `setOnClickListener()` to the view in `onCreateViewHolder()`

Comment: you should use Listener Interface for proper click handling operation

Comment: can you share card_view_list.xml file

Comment: see my updated code

Comment: see my answer this will work for you

Answer (score -2):

It didn't work for me too, what I did was give an id to the root layout element in my row layout (which in your case is `card_view_list`). Then reference it in my `ViewHolder` and set the click listener to that view. Try it out.

Hope it helps.